# Generically finite projection $\pi_L: X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ from plane $L$ and critical points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, surfaces

(In following we are working in "classical" complex setting: i.e. all involved schemes are considered to be varieties over $k=\mathbb{C}$)
Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be irreducible *surface* and $L $ some general $(n-3)$-plane disjoint from $X$.
We consider now the projection map $f = \pi_L: X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ from $L$.

Let $Z \subset X$ be the locus of *critical points*, i.e. points $p \in X$ that are singular or such that the tangent map $df_p: T_pX \to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{P}^2$ has a non trivial kernel
$\text{Ker}(df_p) \neq 0 $. It's a fact that this is a proper closed subset of $X$.
Let $B = f(Z)$ be it's image in $\mathbb{P}^2$ which by properness of $f$ has to be closed too. $B$ is from naive point of
view given as union of a plane curve and a finite collection of some points.

There is an interesting remark in Harris' book *[Algebraic Geometry](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9780387977164)*, on p 290 in proof of Prop. 18.10
that one knows moreover that $B$ has *no* $0$-dimensional components. Unfortunately this fact is not needed for the rest
of the proof, so the author not gave a justification for this.

*Question:* How to check this last statement? Ot looks rather counterintuitive, since thinking of contractions of curves one might expect $B$ might have $0$-dimensional components.

Thoughts: It seems not to be true for all generically finite projective morphisms $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ of surfaces,
since for example the blowup at center $0 \in \mathbb{P}^2$ gives $B=0$. So if the statement is true then it must be based on
special structure of projections from linear subspaces, but I not find an argument. I also not know how "deep" this result is, ie which "tools" are required to prove it. Even if the quoted book is for undergrades, Harris often quotes there some facts going far beyond the scope of the book, and so I'm not sure if this property of $B$ is a result of advanced research or can it be seen with rather "elmentary" tools.

Comment: This type of result is called "purity of the branch locus."  Here's a discussion with some references in the stacks project: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BMB

Comment: @SamirCanning: Thank you, this looks rather promising. So it seems that we can extract 
from this purity result the following: if $f: X \to Y$ is a **finite**
map of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ with $X$ normal and $Y$ smooth (regular
suffice), then the branch locus has pure codimension one.

Comment: By the way: is the term "branch locus" in modern setting
compatible with the old or "classical" notation of the "image
of *critical points*" $Z$ as defined in the question?

Comment: I assume in following that branch locus in the question 
is the same as $B=f(Z)$
in the question, please correct me if I'm wrong. Let come back to our
generically finite morphism $\pi_L: X \to \mathbb{P}^2$. 
There is an open subset 
$U \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ over which $\pi_L$ the fibers are finite and
over the closed complement $C:=\mathbb{P}^2-U$ all the fibers
have *positive* dimension, ie "non finite locus".

Comment: If the notations of branch locus and $B=f(Z)$ in the question 
coinside, then the branch locus equals to the union
of the closed $C$ and the branch locus of the restriction of $\pi_L$
to preimage of $U$, which is finite. So we can split the problem to analyze 
$C$ and the finite restriction $(\pi_L)_{\vert V}$, where
$V:= \pi_L^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: **Problem #1:** I'm not sure if $C$ has always codimension one 
(see the example with blowup at a point

**Problem #2:** $V$ is not neccessary normal (in order to apply *purity theorem*).
Ideas how to cope with this: **Idea (A)** precompose $(\pi_L)_{\vert V}$
with normalization $N:\overline{V} \to U$ and 
compare the branch loci of $(\pi_L)_{\vert V}$ and 
$(\pi_L)_{\vert V} \circ N: \overline{V} \to U$. But I not know 
if it's possible or if there are some results known

Comment: **Idea (B)** Restrict $V$ to smooth points $V_{sm}$
(these are normal) and apply purity to $(\pi_L)_{\vert V_{sm}}$. 
Problem: There is no reason why the singular locus of $V$ should
have pure codimension one?

Comment: Do you maybe see how to circumvent some of the described problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism $f$ is not just generically finite but finite. I think this resolves all the difficulties.

To see this, since $f$ is proper it just suffices to check it is quasi-finite, and thus to check the fiber over a point can't contain a curve. But the fiber over a point is a $(n-2)$-plane containing $L$, and any curve in an $(n-2)$-plane intersects every $(n-3)$-plane, so if such a curve were contained in the fiber it would contradict the assumption that $X$ is disjoint from $L$.

Alternately, we can argue that $\mathbb P^n \setminus L \to \mathbb P^2$ is affine and thus $f$ is affine, and, since affine and proper, is finite.

Comment: Thank you, I see. But one problem stays still unsolved (compare with comments above): to apply purity here we have to ensure $X$ is normal, but Harris not assumed this. Can this problem be somehow fixed? Eg passing to normailzation of $X$ or restrict the map to smooth locus? But both naive approach are seemingly flawed, as in comments explained.

Comment: @user7391733 No, I think normality is necessary for the conclusion to hold. If $X$ is obtained by gluing together two smooth points in a smooth surface then I think a generic projection will have the image of the glued point as an isolated point of the branch locus.

Comment: I see, presumingly Harris assumed $X$ indeed to be even smooth, 
this reduction make sense since the goal was to show that for 
$X$ irreducible, the intersection $Y:= X \cap H$ with general hyperplane
$H$ is irreducible and a general hyperplane intersects $X$ in 
smooth locus, so we can assume $X$ to be even smooth.

Comment: One question about your counterexample showing that "normality"
cannot be dropped: Is this example with gluing two points 
on a smooth surface of "algebraic" or only "analytic" nature? Clearly 
we can construct such pathologies topologically and analytic/holomorphic
functions are "flexible" enough to allow to implement such 
gluing construction to analytic geometry. Algebraic geometry 
is in that sense more "rigid", so I'm not sure why such identification
of two points on a smooth surface (or even weirder identifications) 
works here in algebraic realm?

Comment: @user7391733 Some gluings are hard to construct in the category of schemes but gluing pairs of points are relatively easy (one can consider first the case of an affine variety and do it by algebra). In general, gluings may not exist in the category of schemes but will in the category of algebraic spaces - the category of algebraic spaces is about as powerful as the category of analytic spaces for this.